# Error using authlogic for login: :Can't mass-assign protected attributes:

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, authlogic

I 'm using authlogic for authentication and using [this](http://www.logansbailey.com/2010/10/06/how-to-setup-authlogic-in-rails-3/) tutorial. I did refer to [rubyDocs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment) also. If I understand it correctly that attr_protected method ensures  list of attributes will not be accessible for mass-assignment. And I have my model attributes as protected. I also tried changing the whitelist flag in config/application.rb to false..which didnt make any difference.

I think the problem might be because of no attribute called password & password_confirmation in user model. This is what the tutorial says

> We changed the field name from :crypted_password to :password.
>   Authlogic will map the :password field to :crypted_password after
>   hashing it. We also changed the field type from f.text_field to
>   f.password_field, this will create your standard password input field
>   instead of a plain text input field. We have also added a
>   :password_confirmation field. All of the logic to support these fields
>   is built into authlogic.

Is this still true? Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Rails: 3.2.12

Ruby:  1..9.3

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in UsersController#create

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: password, password_confirmation

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"WUw09PvSlIxLUBFFsi1hiK6v0Y3nn7wqkjH3seCkU34=",
 "user"=>{"username"=>"test",
 "email"=>"test",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Create User"}
```

Following is my model & controller

**MODEL**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :crypted_password, :email, :password_salt, :persistence_token, :username
end
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

FORM.html

```
div class="field">
    <%= f.label :username %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that, as you said, your attributes are protected so they cannot be mass assigned. Make them accessible by adding to the `attr_accessible` list

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :crypted_password, :email, :password_salt, :persistence_token, :username, :password, :password_confirmation
end
```

NOTE: You might also want to remove sensitive data from that list like `:crypted_password` or `:password_salt`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :persistence_token, :username, :password, :password_confirmation
end
```